# Validar que una imagen no esta vacía con javascript

Tags: javascript, img, src

Necesito obtener el nombre de una imagen con javascript, pero cuando el nombre  esta vació me da como resultado "index.html", ¿Cómo puedo validar que la imagen no este vacía? cuando la imagen existe, por consola obtengo el nombre de la imagen ("sinimagen.png") pero cuando esta vació el `src` me muestra "index.html".

```js
// Aca puede obtener todo el nombre imagen.jpg
   var fullPath = document.getElementById("imageA").src;

   // Aca solo el nombre imagen
   var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

   if(filename == ""){
      console.log("No hay imagen: " + filename);
   } else {
      console.log("nombre imagen: " + filename);
   }
var fullPath2 = document.getElementById("imageB").src;

var filename2 = fullPath2.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

 if(filename2 == ""){
    console.log("No hay imagen: " + filename2);
 } else {
    console.log("nombre imagen: " + filename2);
 }
```

```html
<img src="img/sinimagen.png" id="imageA" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;"/>
<img src="" id="imageB" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esto deberia resolverlo:

```
var fullPath = document.getElementById("imageA").src;

// Aca solo el nombre imagen
 var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

filename != "" ? console.log('nombre imagen' +filename) : console.log('no hay 
imagen');
```

Nota que filename toma un valor "" cuando no hay src

velo funcionando aca: https://jsfiddle.net/cgk0a46v/8/

Comment: era lo que necesitaba estuve cerca gracias

Answer (score 3):

Cuando obtienes el valor del `src` de una imagen, lo que obtienes es la url actual de la pagina (`http://ejemplo.com/`) más el nombre de la imagen (`imagen.jpg`) para tener la dirección actual (que seria en este caso `http://ejemplo.com/imagen.jpg`). Si la `src` de la imagen esta vacia (`src=""`) obtienes la **url actual** sin el nombre de una imagen (no una cadena vacía) y por eso el código no funciona.

Para que funcione como quieres te sugiero primero comparar la `src` con `window.location` que es donde se almacena la url actual para saber si esta vació y luego continuas como el siguiente código.

```js
// Aca puede obtener todo el nombre imagen.jpg
   var fullPath = document.getElementById("imageA").src;
      console.log(fullPath);
   if(fullPath == window.location){
      console.log("No hay imagen: ");
   } else {
   // Aca solo el nombre imagen
      var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
      console.log("nombre imagen: " + filename);
   }
```

```html
<img src="" id="imageA" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid blue;">
```

Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos.